# Does each Activity need to Bind to a Service & What happens when it was created with startService()

Tags: android, binding, service, android-activity

I have a Service that is supposed to maintain a constant connection with a home automation controller (HAC). In the preferences of the App, I will give the User a choice to stay** connected to the HAC or to drop the connection to the HAC when the App is not in use. I intend to use startService(), with a look at the preferences to see if it's necessary to call stopSelf() from within the Service.

I basically have two questions:

1. Is it necessary to Bind to the service from every Activity in the App? (I'm finding that the onBind() doesn't seem to execute after my SplashScreen Activity has started and binded to the Service). I even commented out the call to bindService() from an Activity and I'm still able to use the calls the Service. I was hoping to use the onBind() callback to verify if the Service still has a valid connection to the HAC.
2. If I use startService(), and then bindService(); will unBindService() then allow the service to stop if there are no other objects bound? Also, if I start the service with bindService() and then subsequently call startService(); what happens? I'm trying to understand how these two approaches to interacting with the Service affect the lifecycle.

Thanks,
J

** I realize this can be detrimental to battery life, but sometimes it's nice when the NotificationManager tells you that the Motion Detector on your front porch has just been tripped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a Service that is supposed to maintain a constant connection with a home automation controller (HAC). In the preferences of the App, I will give the User a choice to stay** connected to the HAC or to drop the connection to the HAC when the App is not in use. I intend to use startService(), with a look at the preferences to see if it's necessary to call stopSelf() from within the Service.

This is a refreshingly rational and sensible approach -- let the user control how her device is being used. Kudos!

> Is it necessary to Bind to the service from every Activity in the App?

It is not necessary to bind to the service from any activity in the app, if you are using `startService()` to start it.

> I was hoping to use the onBind() callback to verify if the Service still has a valid connection to the HAC.

Particularly for lightweight, read-only, not-likely-to-cause-GC-issues stuff like a connection status, I'd just stick it in a static data member. Now, if you need a more complex API than that, then you'll need binding, but binding is a pain in various body parts when it comes to configuration changes (e.g., screen rotations).

> If I use startService(), and then bindService(); will unBindService() then allow the service to stop if there are no other objects bound?

No, the `startService()` will keep it around, regardless of `unbindService()`.

> Also, if I start the service with bindService() and then subsequently call startService(); what happens?

Ummm...can you be more specific? I mean, I feel reasonably comfortable in saying that your sequence of events will not cause a rupture in the space-time continuum, nor will it cause me to spontaneously grow hair. :-)

Comment: Without the binder object, I would access the fields and methods statically?

Comment: @tunneling: Again, for something as simple as reading the current status, a static data member (e.g., int or String or enum) should be fine. If you need anything much more complex than that, you will need to use binding.

Comment: To be more specific... I thought about starting the service using both bindService() [for short life] and startService() [for long life]. So I was just trying to understand the dynamics of how making calls to these methods (in various sequences) would affect the lifecycle of the Service.

Comment: @tunneling: Order does not really matter. If there is an outstanding `startService()` when the last `unbindService()` is called, the service keeps running. If there isn't, the service will stop.

Comment: @CommonsWare: In the Service, I start a Connection thread which is responsible for keeping the connection as well as sending and receiving commands. The Service serves as the Apps interface to the Connection. So, the goal is to verify that the connection is still live before the Activities start passing commands to the controller. The real problem is when the device(android) goes to sleep and the Connection thread stops talking with the HAC. When we wake back up, if the static variable shows CONNECTED, then the Activity tries to refresh data from the HAC, but the remote socket has been closed.

Comment: @tunneling: When the device wakes up, your thread will catch the socket exception and update the static data member. It is conceivable the activity could try reading the data member before that occurs, but it seems somewhat unlikely. Moreover, it's an edge case you will encounter in other scenarios as well (WiFi connections aren't exactly the Rock of Gibraltar), so your activity will need to have some actual error handling, that's all. But, again, if you are binding for other reasons ("the Activity tries to refresh data from the HAC"), then feel free to skip the static data member approach.