# How do I get an IBinder/ServiceConnection/onServiceConnected when starting a Service with startService?

Tags: android, service

I have been looking for some way to get the ServiceConnection when I start my Service using startService(...).

I haven't found a way, so I have been searching a bit and found this:
[Does each Activity need to Bind to a Service & What happens when it was created with startService()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010310/does-each-activity-need-to-bind-to-a-service-what-happens-when-it-was-created-w)

There, Commonsware says that it doesn't matter if I call bindService after the startService call.

So I thought that I first run startService(...) and then directly after do a bindService(...) (so that onServiceConnected is called). But then the Service.onCreate is executed twice. Probably because startService isn't "finished" yet...?

**Question is: How do I get a reference to my Service (the IBinder), ie. how do I get the onServiceConnected to fire if I start my Service with startService?**

--- EDIT ---

I still do want to know any answers and ideas you might have. I made a "hack" to get around this:

I simply made a static reference (in `SRef.java` I have public `static IBinder myBinder = null)`, and in my `Service.onCreate` I simple do

```
SRef.myBinder = myBinder;
```

This doesn't seem right to me, so any other ideas on how it is supposed to work would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I use the exact same technique (a samba client service), `onCreate` is never called twice for me and I get the binder (by connection callback) as I would expect. A new start of activity doesn't fire a `onCreate` either because previous `startService` performed the startup of the service already.

Here is my code (might be trivial, but maybe it helps):

Activity (`onCreate`):

```
startService(new Intent(this, SambaService.class));
bindService(new Intent(this, SambaService.class), sambaServiceConnection,
        Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Service:

```
private ServiceBinder mServiceBinder = new ServiceBinder();

public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
    public SambaService getService() {
        return SambaService.this;
    }
}

public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mServiceBinder;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did the startService and bindSerbie, but onCreate was indeed executed twice. Weird. I'll have to try it again at some point. Right now Im going with the Static variable as noted in the edit.